# very hard and elegant question on shortest path

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

Given a weighed, connected and directed graph `G=(V,E)` with `n` vertexes and `m` edges, and given a pre-calculated shortest path distance's matrix `S` where `S` is `n*n` `S(i,j)` denotes the weight of shortest path from vertex `i` to vertex `j`.

we know just weight of one edge `(u, v)` is changed (increased or decreased).

for two specific vertex `s` and `t`  we want to update the shortest path length between these two vertex.

This can be done in `O(1).`

How is this possible? what is the trick of this answer?

Comment: Who said this? I'm pretty sure there's a cell-probe lower bound that says we can't.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're asking? It's clear that the weight of one edge is changed. However it's completely unclear what exactly information we receive, and what we're supposed to do with this information. Do we know which edge was updated? Do we know the old value? What do we need to do with this information? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can for decreases. I assume `S` will always refer to the old distances. Let `l` be the new distance between `(u, v)`. Check if

```
S(s, u) + l + S(v, t) < S(s, t)
```

if yes then the left hand side is the new optimal distance between `s` and `t`.

---

Increases are impossible. Consider the following graph (edges in red have zero weight):

[image: https://i.imgur.com/94LjDYt.png]

Suppose `m` is the minimum weight edge here, except for `(u, v)` which used to be lower. Now we update `(u, v)` to some weight `l > m`. This means we must find `m` to find the new optimum length.

Suppose we could do this in O(1) time. Then it means we could find the minimum of any array in O(1) time by feeding it into this algorithm after adding `(u, v)` with weight `-BIGNUMBER` and then 'updating' it to `BIGNUMBER` (we can lazily construct the distance matrix because all distances are either `0`, `inf` or just the edge weights). That is clearly not possible, thus we can't solve this problem in O(1) either.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph The increase is not possible, see my updated answer.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph Those are describing dynamic all pairs **data structures**, which is entirely different input than what you described (a simple `n*n` all pairs matrix).

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph That doesn't imply O(1) is possible. O(n) is sufficient and necessary and it isn't that hard to come up with (to update just `S(s, t)`).

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph I'm sorry, I'm losing interest. You keep changing the requirements/input/output. These kind of problems are just very sensitive to that. If you want all updates that's very different than just a single update...

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph For decrease that's correct.

Comment: @orlp if there exists only one path between ```s``` and ```t``` that goes through ```u->v```, then an increase would be possible?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur No, see my example above, it only has one path that goes through `(u, v)`.